# Python - Find closest indices from 2 sets

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, scipy

I have 2 sets of indices (i,j).
What I need to get is  the 2 indices that are closest from the 2 sets.
It is easier to explain graphically:

[image]

Assuming I have all the indices that make the first black shape, and all the indices that make the second black shape, how do I find the closest indices (the red points in the figure) between those 2 shapes, in an efficient way (built in function in Python, not by iterating through all the possibilities)?

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: I would take a look at this
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closest_pair_of_points_problem

Comment: Looks like you need to find the [connected components](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_(graph_theory)) and then find the pairs of coordinates from both sets with a smaller euclidean distance. A minimal reproducible example would help.

Comment: Did you consider the `scipy.spatial.distance` module? I think that there is no way around computing the distances between all pair combinations, but the `scipy` module can at least do it from compiled code.

Comment: You may want to have a look at `scipy.spatial.cKDTree`.

Answer (score 1):

As you asked about a built in function rather than looping through all combinations, there's a method in scipy.spacial.distance that does just that - it outputs a matrix of distances between all pairs of 2 inputs. If A and B are collections of 2D points, then:

```
from scipy.spatial import distance  
dists = distance.cdist(A,B)
```

Then you can get the index of the minimal value in the matrix.